# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java

```
// Station Data                                                                 
private static final Object[][] dataFromSpace = new Object[][] {                        
     {"Ram garh",45,110, "munshi jee"}
    ,{"Pluto",1000000,-50000,"Thor"}
    ,{"Jhumritaliya",66,110,null}
    ,{"Ram garh-Jr",45.9,110,null}
    ,{"planet-X",56E4+1,Double.NaN,null}
};
private List<S> stations=new ArrayList<S>();

testCore_JavA_SpaceRoutePlanner() throws RuntimeException {                     
    for(int row = 0; row < dataFromSpace.length; row++) {
                    System.out.println(dataFromSpace[row][1]);
                    S s = (S)new Station(
            (String)dataFromSpace[row][0],
                            (int)dataFromSpace[row][1],
            (int)dataFromSpace[row][2],
            (String)dataFromSpace[row][3]
        );

        stations.add(s);
    }
}
```

Error is occurring in line (int)dataFromSpace[row][1] and (int)dataFromSpace[row][1]

It gives error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: it is clear in exception, then what is your question ?

Comment: how do I solve the Exception?

Comment: cast with Double

Answer (score 1):

You probably cast it to double like this:

`(double) dataFromSpace[row][2],`